# mongo text search using $text is not working

Tags: mongodb, text, full-text-search

I am trying to do mongo text search using indexing and $text

The model i have is

```
var authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        authorId : Number,
        Description : String,
        firstName : String
    });

authorSchema.index({ firstName: 'text'});
```

i am creating the index on first name

when i do the search  as shown below

```
router.route('/search')
    .get(function(req,res){
        Authors.find({ $text : { $search : req.params.search }},{"_id":0,"firstName":1},function(err,authors){
            res.send(authors);
        })
    })
```

search seems not to provide expected result ie,

I have two documents in the collection where the first name is kumar and sam kumar 
*When i search for kumar search  will get both the documents
*When i search  for  sam kumar i will again get both the documents which seems to be not right what is expected is search is only sam kumar

What am i doing wrong

Please say how can i accomplish the search when i search for entire first name search should return only single document

Comment: Make sure that the index has been created. Fire up Mongo Shell, and get the indexes on your collection by `db.collection_name.getIndexes()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to find phrase, in your case **sam kumar** and trying to find a document which contains full phrase.

in this case, wrap your phrase with double quotes (")

e.g.

```
var phrase = "\"" + req.params.search + "\"";

Authors.find({ $text : { $search : phrase }},{"_id":0,"firstName":1},function(err,authors){
        res.send(authors);
```

this should return what are you expecting.

here is documentation stating how to search phrases. 
please see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases

Above snipes assume that you are search for a complete phrase **sam kumar**. However if you want to match all documents where both words **sam** and **kumar** exists anywhere in document, then you'll need to calculate text score and filter documents with score of 1 or more.

Please see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/#match-on-text-score for reference.

Comment: Nope. That would be `var phrase = "\\\"" + req.params.search + "\\\"";` since the "\" is an escape character for strings and is required both before itself and the `"` to be interpolated. What you typed would set the `phrase` variable to `"+req.params.search+"` rather than `\"Sam Kumar\"`, which would be using the variable value.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, I guess you unintentionally typed two extra `\\\`

Comment: Yes of course. It's an esape character. So when you want the characters "\" or `"` inside of a string quoted with `"` you need to preceed the actual charcter you want with an escape character. Which is of course commonly "\" in quite a few languages, and certainly for JavaScript. BTW the quotes `""` around the slash are just to make it stand out, you just use the slash. And it's also an escape charater in code references on this site. Hence why it is not marked that way in in comment of mine here.